# Работа с Pycharm + Node.js + SSH возможна?

Tags: node.js, ssh, pycharm

Всем привет.
Сам верстальщик и на данный момент возникла необходимость в работе с node.js + SSH.
Используя параметры хостинга и клиент Putty - проблем с подключением через SSH не возникло.
Но вот при работе с Pycharm появились некоторые проблемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С одной стороны удалось приконектится и файлы которые лежат у меня на облачном хостинге видны.
(удается производить операции по обмену данными)

С другой стороны - в консоли, в которой как я понимаю должна быть видна командная строка, 
которая ожидает команды для удаленного сервера - вообще не работает и выдается ошибка
(на скрине нижняя указательная стрелка.)

Путь к Node.js указал тот который мне дала служба поддержки хостинга:


[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот путь реально существует и это можно увидеть справа в панели:


[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же в логах можно увидеть следующее сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос:
Что я делаю не так?

P.S. Буду благодарен за любые советы и рекомендации.
(за возможность зацепиться за решение проблемы.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена с помощью следующего пункта меню:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]